# Hide 3 of the 5 rows in a name range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a name range that has 5 rows and 6 columns. I want to hide 3 rows out of the 5 rows. I'm only able to get one of the rows. How would I specify the other rows i need to be hidden?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim theTargetRow, initialStartRow As String
initialStartRow = "113"
theTargetRow = initialStartRow + Target.Value
If Target.Value = "---" Then
    Range("myNameRange").Rows.Hidden = True
Else
    'Range("myNameRange").Rows.Hidden = True
    For rowCounter = theTargetRow To initialStartRow + 1 Step -1
        Rows(rowCounter).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Next           
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: I got it work by removing my namerange from the rows i needed to be hidden.

Comment: `For... Each` statement is probably necessary.

Comment: How do you know which of the rows you want to hide?  Is it row "113" - if so what happens if row 113 isn't in the named range?  `initialStartRow` should be a `long` rather than a `string`,  `theTargetRow` should also be a `long` rather than a `variant`.

Comment: I got it work by removing my namerange from the rows i needed to be hidden.

Comment: Better yet, remove `initialStartRow`, set your range to what you are wanting to search for, like `Dim myRng as Range` `Set myRng = Range("113:117")`. Then we can search the specified range for the criteria you need. You need to not make `theTargetRow` as type Variant, because you are adding a range and a value of a cell together with line `theTargetRow = initialStartRow + Target.Value`, which makes no sense on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

With you providing limited information, I can only give limited information back to you (more specifically, the below code is searching every single cell in your range because I am not sure what column `N/A` is located in).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim Target As Range, Cell As Range
    Set Target = Range("myNameRange")

    For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Value = "N/A" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: not trying to hide all the rows, i'm only trying to hide the number of rows. recheck my post. i got the loop but the row is not showing.

Comment: I got it work by removing my namerange from the rows i needed to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the ith row of your named Range...

```
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("myNameRange").Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: recheck my edit post, seems like i got the loop to work but my row is still not showing visible.

Comment: I got it work by removing my namerange from the rows i needed to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the first three rows in a named range, although by the solution you found that worked for you it seems you want to hide just rows - not necessarily within a named range.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    For Each rCell In Range("myNameRange").Rows
        If i < 3 Then
            rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next rCell

End Sub
```